# How to execute one command of the script as a normal user?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, runas

I run the entire script as an administrator, but how to execute one of the script commands run as a normal user - not as an administrator? For example run last one command **OneDrive.exe** as normal user?

I'm start script.bat as administrator

```
taskkill /im fssoma.exe /F
taskkill /im FctSecSvr.exe /F
echo Services Stoped
echo Enter password:
manage-bde -unlock d: -password 
echo Drive D is Unlocked
echo
cd \
if exist 'D:\OneDrive - test' echo 'yes'
cd \
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive"
OneDrive.exe
```

Comment: You cannot unelevate from elevated.

Comment: you can do `runas /savecred /noprofile /user:username OneDrive.exe` or if you need to run other commands within `cmd` then `runas /savecred /noprofile /user:username "cmd /c onerdrive.exe"` however, you would need to initially specify the password for `/savecred` to remember it. So if you are planning on running this only on your own PC it should be ok.